# What would we buy for our new planet?

Tags: environment, economy, alternate-worlds, terraforming

I recently read that the combined wealth on earth is £146 trillion. If we divide that by the worlds population of 7 billion we get approximately £21k.

My question is **If the human race was transported to a planet like earth except it was just rock, air and empty oceans what would we buy from earth to bring over?**

The new planet has rain, weather, tides etc but no life including plant life.

Don't worry about the logistics of bringing things from earth, the most important thing is what would you buy and how it would benefit the human race.

For example you could say you would buy 7 billion 1 man tents or I would get together with my friends and buy a vineyard to bring over.

Points go to intelligent and or humorous answers.

**EDIT:**

Try to go for practical items that would allow for sustainable human life. I would also prefer that you incorporate humor in your answers as much as possible while still remaining pertinent to the question.

Comment: I totally love the question, but to my eyes it is too subjective

Comment: I don't think humorous answer are relevant.

Comment: Cheers for the edit

Comment: I feel like the monetary breakdown you start with is superfluous.  An individual person is not going to be buying terraforming equipment...unless they are mad scientists I suppose.  This could potentially be re-framed as a terraforming question but that may make it a duplicate.  I guess, if the logistics are going to be ignored why does the cost matter?  The biggest cost in this case would be transport.

Comment: @James I was originally thinking that people would give a list of things they could buy that they could bring to survive. Like I could bring 4 hens, Cigarettes to trade, canned food, a 6 man tent, a spade etc. Other people would buy things too that were different from your own. I probably didn't phrase the question well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might buy [Winter, the bottle nose Dolphin](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_(dolphin)) for entertainment purposes. If we did that, we would have to buy a bunch of fish, squid and ocean crabs to feed it. Following that logic, we would have to buy a ton of algae for the crabs to eat.

Of course, we all need to breathe so...

We would have to buy about $1.03e+18$ tons (probably way off as I am not too great at math) of oxygen (copied straight out of the calculator) to build the ozone layer on the planet since without life it is debatable whether oxygen could naturally form in sufficient quantities to support human life. I got the information needed to make my calculations from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth).

We would need to oxygenate the oceans with even more oxygen to support our marine life. We would bring a few hundred chimps (again, for entertainment) with us and we would then have to buy all of the organisms that have to exist to support chimps. Buy a few hundred million cows, a few hundred million chickens and a few hundred million pigs for meat and animal products.

Buy grain and the whole sleuth of stuff required to grow and raise it. You might want to buy minerals from Earth because an Earth-like planet without life probably lacks sufficient minerals to sustain it.

We would, of course buy our pre-built factories and have them shipped to this planet in a nice pre-paid postage box. You basically said screw logistics, so why not mail entire pre-built cities like Tokyo and Paris, complete with bedrock and all, to our new home?

Comment: So I know we have a free market, but I'm pretty sure you need to file some paperwork with the SEC before buying that many tons of oxygen ;-)

Comment: @CortAmmon Darn it, I hate paperwork!

Comment: Doesn't algae create a large portion of Earth's oxygen? Plus we are buying it for the dolphin already!

Comment: @DoubleDouble Algae do produce a lot of our Oxygen. I actually listed things we would have to bring in reverse order. To fit the "comedy" condition, you know?

Answer (score 2):

With no plant life, there would be no oxygen, and we'd suffocate immediately. Without any life forms, there would be no carbon sequestration in forests or oil, so this new planet would probably be in runaway greenhouse warming, and we'd be burned alive.  And since the planet is so hot, there's probably not any liquid water on the surface.  So we'd die of thirst.

Oh, don't forget, there's no food.  So we'd starve if we could stay alive that long.

So, what would end up buying?  Nothing, because we're dead.  Really, really, really, really dead.

Comment: So you should have bought a coffin....

Comment: Don't forget crushed by the pressure of all of the evaporated water in the atmosphere. Or starvation due to lack of food chain. Or.......

Comment: So in other words, our new planet looks a lot like Venus.